# What is the efficient way to find the minimum time and date stamp?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have created a table with different timestamps and date. The structure for time and date is as follows:

```
typedef struct structTimeDate
{
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int hours;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} TimeDate;
```

Each row of the table got a `TimeDate`. What I would like to achieve is to find the least `TimeDate` from the table meaning the one with oldest date and time. I thought of iterating the table and writing `if` and `else if` to achieve it and but it seems complicated and error prone.

Is there any existing algorithm which would help to achieve my goal? I am not looking for someone to write me the code. I want a starting point or any algorithm which would suit my requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need a function to compare two `structTimeDate *` cast to `void *` and then you can write a generic algorithm for minimum, akin to the `qsort` and `bsearch` functions of the standard library.

Comment: Are the values of each member in the primarily range?  E.h. 0 <= hours < 24?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Yes, all the values are in range meaning there won't any unsupported date and time. Those are filltered out before filling the table.

Comment: Any algorithm you come up with is likely to use ifs and else ifs. There's nothing inherently complicated about using those. You can either keep the table sorted or iterate the table when you need to find the min.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Exactly, I need a function. But I am thinking about any existing algorithm for my use case. Also, I will take a look at the functions you have mentioned.

Comment: Also, don't you have daylight saving time over there?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, there is. But I can't imagine how that will come into play? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Well, if the minimum is in the _fold_ then you might get the timestamp which has the lowest numbers but it won't be the instant that is earliest.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah right! Think I do not care about such cases.

Comment: Unless one is in [Lord Howe Island](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/australia/lord-howe-island), code can use an `.isdst` flag like an `.hour` adjustment.  If I have the sign right, it is like `hour_to_use_in_computation = .hour - .isdst`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if then else` is not so bad.

```
if (x.year < y.year) return -1;
if (x.year > y.year) return 1;
if (x.month < y.month) return -1;
if (x.month > y.month) return 1;
...
if (x.sec < y.sec) return -1;
if (x.sec > y.sec) return 1;
return 0;
```

---

An alternative:

If one only needs to compare for order and members are in primary range, create an artificial integer time stamp.

```
// Think of date as base 13, 32, 24, 60, 60
long long ts = ((((x.year*13LL + x.month)*32 + x.day)*24 + x.hour)*60 + x.min)*60 + x.sec;
```

Then simply compare the integer value of time stamps to find greatest.

Additional work needed to support negative years.

---

A minor efficiency can be had with using power-of-2 constants.

```
long long ts = ((((x.year*16LL + x.month)*32 + x.day)*32 + x.hour)*64 + x.min)*64 + x.sec;
```

Comment: In fact they will both say that 02:40:00 comes before 03:01:00 as well.

Comment: I guess it should use `ULL` and unsigned integers everywhere to ensure that even more optimizations are possible (including bitshitfs)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True, Could even use `((((x.year*256ULL + x.month)*256 + x.day)*256 + x.hour)*256 + x.min)*256 + x.sec;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Could you please give me an explanation about the base assumptions? I am not understanding that part.

Comment: @Dennis.M E. g. A base 32 number uses the "digits" 0-31. As day-of-the month is 1-31, by multiplying the number of months by 32, code insures that days of a later month are greater than a smaller/equal month.  Code cannot simply add the elements together.  It must first scale the elements in a way to insure months count more than days, days more than hours, etc.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am also trying to experiment the problem with `if then else`. Could you please give me an example with that? Thank you.